# HTML canvas leaves unwanted trails

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to plot the [Bifurcation diagram](https://www.vanderbilt.edu/AnS/psychology/cogsci/chaos/workshop/BD.html) using HTML canvas and JS.
Here's my [tool](https://kboeff.github.io/logistic-equation-tool/).
The problem is the canvas doesn't render the data accurately.

Here's a comparison of what the chart should look like, and how it's actually rendered with my code:
[image: Proper] [image: Messed Up]
And here's a magnified region of the function: [image: A few dots]

I went throught the data set and there seems to be no intermediate values. Thus, my question is - why does the browser leave these unwanted trails between the objects that should be only drawn?
Looks more like a 'connect the dots' type of chart, than a plot of discrete data points.

Here's the part of the code I use for the drawing:

```
// ... get elements, calculate data, etc.
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = canvas.width / 2;
let xSpread = canvas.width / (rMax - rMin);

for (let i in chartData) {
    let x = (i - rMin) * xSpread * scale;
    for (let j in chartData[i]) {
        let y = canvas.height - (chartData[i][j] * canvas.height * scale);
        ctx.arc(x, y, pointSize, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    }
}

ctx.fillStyle = "#0a5e8c";
ctx.fill();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @kbo... i truly think that you need to use `beginPath` and `closePath` in such complex drawings (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/beginPath)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a

```
moveTo(x + pointSize, y);
```

before each

```
ctx.arc(x, y, pointSize, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
```

Without this, it's like you are drawing without lifting your pen.

Comment: You're welcome :). If that's the case, would you accept my answer (by the green tick icon)?

Comment: should be `ctx.arc(x + pointSize, y...`, otherwise you'll draw the line from the center to the arc's  starting position (which is at 3o'clock). Won't really be noticeable with fill(), but definitely with stroke().

Comment: @Kaiido That's right, but in this particular case arc function is used to draw filled dots, and I thought that sum would be a redundant operation.

Comment: That operation is anyway done by the browser. I didn't do a perf-test, but it wouldn't surprise me that if this lineTo is avoided, there will be a win.

Comment: t.m. I tried to accept, but I lack 15 reputation. When I get it, I sure will do. :)